# Using ogr2ogr for clipping vector files

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, clip

I am looking for alternative (more efficient) methods for clipping large feature class datasets. When using the 'Clip' tool in ArcGIS, often times the tool will crash after many hours of processing. Without getting into specifics regarding file size or computation capabilities, I was wondering if there were better methods for clipping large datasets. Looking around on the Web, I've seen GDAL Ogr2Ogr mentioned several times. I was hoping someone could explain what exactly ogr2ogr is and if it truly is a more efficient way to clip data vs. using tools in ArcGIS.

I'm pretty new to the Geospatial field so my technical jargon isn't very vast yet.

The .gdb in question is 4.8 GB with a feature count of 21,858,032 features. ArcMap 10.2 is being used. As for computer specs: Intel Xeon @ 3.50GHz, 32.0 GB of RAM and it's a 64 bit Operating System.

Comment: ArcGIS is very capable of clipping massive datasets. Could you please supply more details?: 1) what are your system specs?, 2) how large are your feature classes?, 3) how many features?, 4) what type of vector geometry (points, lines, polygons), 5) what version of ArcGIS did you use?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Aaron. My colleague is getting me the information you requested. I hope to have that to you by tomorrow afternoon.